# Why does the Cauchy distribution have no mean?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, mean, density-function, cauchy-distribution

From the distribution density function we could identify a mean (=0) for Cauchy distribution just like the graph below shows. But why do we say Cauchy distribution has no mean?

[image]

Comment: I recommend the reference Cabeza G., U. A.. (2013). La Media de la Distribución de Cauchy. In the blog [Apoyo en Matemáticas](http://apoyoenmatematicas.blogspot.com/2012/12/4-la-media-de-la-distribucion-de-cauchy.html) about the mean of Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Se my answer here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94402/what-is-the-difference-between-finite-and-infinite-variance/100161#100161

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can mechanically check that the expected value does not exist, but this should be physically intuitive, at least if you accept [Huygens' principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) and the [Law of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). The conclusion of the Law of Large Numbers fails for a Cauchy distribution, so it can't have a mean. If you average $n$ independent Cauchy random variables, the result does not converge to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ with probability $1$. It stays a Cauchy distribution of the same size. This is important in optics.

The Cauchy distribution is the normalized intensity of light on a line from a point source. Huygens' principle says that you can determine the intensity by assuming that the light is re-emitted from any line between the source and the target. So, the intensity of light on a line $2$ meters away can be determined by assuming that the light first hits a line $1$ meter away, and is re-emitted at any forward angle. The intensity of light on a line $n$ meters away can be expressed as the $n$-fold convolution of the distribution of light on a line $1$ meter away. That is, the sum of $n$ independent Cauchy distributions is a Cauchy distribution scaled by a factor of $n$.

If the Cauchy distribution had a mean, then the $25$th percentile of the $n$-fold convolution divided by $n$ would have to converge to $0$ by the Law of Large Numbers. Instead it stays constant. If you mark the $25$th percentile on a (transparent) line $1$ meter away, $2$ meters away, etc. then these points form a straight line, at $45$ degrees. They don't bend toward $0$.

This tells you about the Cauchy distribution in particular, but you should know the integral test because there are other distributions with no mean which don't have a clear physical interpretation.

Comment: +1 Now *there* is an illuminating answer :-) (sorry).  By the way, the principle is named for Christiaan Huygens, not Huygen.  Huygens was the first to appreciate new developments in probability published in the 1650's by Pascal (based on his letters with Fermat): it was Huygens' account of these ideas (1657), including that of expectation, which originally got probability theory on a mathematical footing and paved the way for the seminal (posthumous) treatise of Jakob Bernoulli (*Ars Conjectandi*, 1713).

Comment: The amplitudes are propagated, not the intensities.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I find the end confusing: "...mark the 25th percentile on ... a straight line, at 45 degrees. They don't bend toward 0." The statement itself is true (as a consequence of Huygens-Fresnel principle), but that is before "divided by $n$". When divide by 2 at 2-meters, divided by 3 at 3-meters, ..., then the transparent line is vertical (perpendicular to screen that captures the light). The 45 degree quantile line belongs to the sum of Cauchy and doesn't help with the argument (yet).

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin - I think there is a simpler end: From the second paragraph, we know that the average of $n$ Cauchy r.v.s is Cauchy. Hence the average can never converge a.s. to a constant so the LLN cannot apply.

Answer (score 50):

Answer added in response to @whuber's comment on Michael Chernicks's answer
(and re-written completely to remove the error pointed out by whuber.)

The value of the integral for the expected value of a Cauchy random variable 
is said to be undefined because the value can be "made" to be
anything one likes.  The integral 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx$$
(interpreted in the sense of a Riemann integral)
is what is commonly called an improper integral and its
value must be computed as a limiting value:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx
= \lim_{T_1\to-\infty}\lim_{T_2\to+\infty}
\int_{T_1}^{T_2} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx$$
or
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx
= \lim_{T_2\to+\infty}\lim_{T_1\to-\infty}
\int_{T_1}^{T_2} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx$$
and or course, both evaluations should give the same
finite value. If not, the integral is said to be 
undefined.  This immediately shows why the
mean of the Cauchy random variable is said to be
undefined: the limiting value in the inner limit
diverges.

The Cauchy principal value is obtained as a single
limit: 
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}
\int_{-T}^{T} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx$$
instead of the double limit above. The
principal value of the expectation integral is easily 
seen to be $0$ since the
limitand has value $0$ for all $T$. But this
cannot be used to say that the mean of a Cauchy
random variable is $0$. That is, the mean is defined
as the value of the integral in the usual sense and
not in the principal value sense.

For $\alpha > 0$, consider instead the integral 
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-T}^{\alpha T} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx
&= \int_{-T}^{T} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx
+ \int_{T}^{\alpha T} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx\\
&= 0 + \left.\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{2\pi}\right|_T^{\alpha T}\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{1+\alpha^2T^2}{1+T^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{\alpha^2+T^{-2}}{1+T^{-2}}\right)
\end{align}$$
which approaches a limiting value of 
$\displaystyle \frac{\ln(\alpha)}{\pi}$ as  $T\to\infty$.
When $\alpha = 1$, we get the principal value $0$ discussed
above. Thus, we cannot assign an unambiguous meaning to
the expression
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx$$
without specifying how the two infinities were approached,
and to ignore this point leads to all sorts of complications
and incorrect results because things are not always what
they seem when the milk of principal value masquerades as the
cream of value. This is why the mean of the Cauchy
random variable is said to be undefined rather than have
value $0$, the principal value of the integral.

---

If one is using the measure-theoretic approach to
probability and  the expected value integral is
defined in the sense of a Lebesgue integral, then
the issue is simpler. $\int g$ exists only when
$\int |g|$ is finite, and so $E[X]$ is undefined
for a Cauchy random variable $X$ since $E[|X|]$ is
not finite.

Comment: The evaluation of the middle integral is incorrect: it's zero, not a logarithm. The problem actually lies with evaluating the two limits implicit in the infinite integrals.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for pointing out the error.  I have completely re-written my answer and your comment no longer applies.

Comment: I don't understand why the expectation of the ratio doesn't exist. If $ X $ and $ Y $ are jointly normally distributed with mean different than zero, then the mean of $ Z = \frac{X}{Y} $ is given by $ \int \int \frac{x}{y} p \left( x, y \right) dx dy $, what am I missing?

Comment: @Drazick I have not mentioned the ratio of two normal random variables anywhere in my answer. Please ask someone who has raised this issue with respect to Cauchy random variables.

Comment: I'm saying that this is also the distribution of the ratio of two Normally Distributed R.V. Hence I can understand the math of the non converging integral, yet don't understand why my assertion won't hold.

Comment: @Drazick Look into whether your integral _exists_ at all. In general, if the density of $X$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $0$, E[X^{-1}]$ does not exist.

Comment: A good reason for not taking the principle value is stated in [the answer by user "kjetil b halvorsen"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36142/131145), which is not addressed in the (many) comments for another answer by Michael Chernick. His wording is confusing, though.

Comment: your paragraph leaves a little space for Cauchy mean being an improper integral

Answer (score 43):

While the above answers are valid explanations of why the Cauchy distribution has no expectation, I find the fact that the ratio $X_1/X_2$ of two independent normal $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ variates is Cauchy just as illuminating: indeed, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{|X_1|}{|X_2|} \right] =
\mathbb{E}\left[ |X_1| \right] \times \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{|X_2|} \right] 
$$
and the second expectation is $+\infty$.

Comment: Is $\left|\frac{X_1}{X_2}\right|$ a 'folded' Cauchy random variable when I know that $\frac{X_1}{X_2}$ is standard Cauchy? How can one find the distribution of $\left|\frac{X_1}{X_2}\right|$?

Comment: Yes, this is the absolute value of a Cauchy variate, which has thus the density $f(x)+f(-x)$ over the positive real numbers.

Comment: If you fold the normal distribution, then $\mathbb{E} 1/|X_2|$ is not infinity?

Comment: It is infinity.

Answer (score 27):

The Cauchy has no mean because the point you select (0) is not a mean.  It is a *median* and a *mode*.  The mean for an absolutely continuous distribution is defined as $\int x f(x) dx$ where $f$ is the density function and the integral is taken over the domain of $f$ (which is $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in the case of the Cauchy).  For the Cauchy density, this integral is simply not finite (the half from $-\infty$ to $0$ is $-\infty$ and the half from $0$ to $\infty$ is $\infty$).

Comment: Could you explain why the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)\,dx$ is "simply infinite" as you claim? Most people would say that the integral is _undefined_ since it works out to be of the form $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: That's true, @Dilip.  Moreover, the integral has a well defined [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value): and it's equal to zero. :-)

Comment: Okay not defined is better terminology. Both halves are infinite and cannot be added.

Comment: @whuber I am well aware that the integral has a well-defined principal value (often called the _Cauchy_ principal value too) and that the principal value is equal to zero. I merely wished Michael to explain why he was claiming the value of the integral to be $\infty$ (which is not the principal value either).

Comment: @DilipSarwate You made a good point and i modified my answer.  Let us not lose track of the fact that the OP had a misconception of what the definition of a mean is.  The point is that the integral defining the mean does not converge to any finite value like 0.

Comment: I'm not criticizing you, @Dilip: I'm augmenting your observation.  What is very interesting is that the existence of a zero principal value might tempt us to define the mean of the Cauchy distribution (or the mean of any RV) as the principal value of the integral. This probes much more deeply into the nature of this question, which is glossed over by declaring that the integral is either infinite or undefined: namely, *why doesn't the principal value work*?  Why would it not be legitimate to use that as a mean?

Comment: @whuber It is also interesting that if you truncate the integral at -a and +a for any a>0 you get 0. So taking the limit as a approaches ∞ of the symmetric integral gives 0.  Another reason to ask why isn't 0 the mean.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right Michael: you have in fact described how the principal value is obtained.

Comment: Oh I wasn't sure that I was saying the same thing. Thanks @whuber.

Comment: @whuber: I take your last question in your penultimate remark to be rhetorical; at any rate we want absolute convergence and "the" reason in my mind is that we want things to behave like areas. In particular, we need to be able to chop things (functions) into pieces and rearrange them at will without disturbing the answer we obtain. We cannot do this chopping and rearranging for a linear function wrt a Cauchy distribution, so we must insist that its mean does not exist.

Comment: That, @cardinal, is a good answer! I wasn't merely being rhetorical, because the question itself asks "why do we say [the] Cauchy distribution has no mean?" Asserting the expectation is undefined may satisfy the uncurious, but the possibility that a reasonable alternative definition of the integral may exist--and yields an intuitively correct answer!--ought to trouble people. Your answer is close to what I had in mind, but it's still incomplete. I think a satisfactory answer would identify important theorems of statistical theory that fail when we work with conditionally convergent integrals.

Comment: @whuber: I was having trouble fitting the last point you mention into 600 characters! ;-) I, myself, first encountered this Cauchy example having only an introductory calculus background at the time and I remember puzzling over it for quite some time. It is unfortunate, because it is *so* irritating to have only a flippant and unsatisfactory explanation at hand and so I can empathize with the OP.

Comment: @whuber Most theorems in statistics and probability that begin with "Let ... be random variable(s) with finite mean.." do not hold for Cauchy random variables and so defining the mean as the principal value will break all such theorems, requiring them to be re-written to say "finite mean in the usual sense and not the principal value sense" and create even more muddles....

Comment: @Dilip I thought so too, but upon reflection find this to be a little more challenging than you seem to suggest. For instance, there's no problem with the Central Limit Theorem: requiring a variance automatically guarantees an expectation, of course. And a lot of theorems are proven using Chebyshev's Inequality, where once more we're guaranteed a mean. So I really am curious: what are the big theorems used in the practice of statistics where we really have to be cognizant of the problems with conditionally convergent, but not convergent, expectations?

Comment: @whuber Perhaps including statistics was too strong but in probability theory, (at least one form of) the strong law of large numbers says that the sample mean of iid random variables with finite mean $\mu$ converges to $\mu$ with probability $1$. As you know and as Douglas Zare noted in his accepted answer, the sample mean of standard Cauchy samples has standard Cauchy distribution. So if one defines the mean of a standard Cauchy random variable as $0$ based on the principal value, then the SLLN would have to be re-written. Jensen's Inequality also requires that the expectations be finite.

Comment: @whuber (continued) but perhaps these results are not of importance in statistical _practice._

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: of course they are important in statistical practice!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen My suggestion that SLLN and Jensen's Inequality might not be important in statistical practice was occasioned by Moderator whuber's question "what are the big theorems used in the practice of statistics where we really have to be cognizant of the problems with conditionally convergent, but not convergent, expectations?". I am _not_ a statistician and have no knowledge of what statistical practice is like. Perhaps practicing statisticians never need to use SLLN or Jensen's Inequality....

Comment: @whuber Principal value of the integral does come into play in Feller's form of WLLN: if $xP(|X|>x)\to 0$, then $\frac {S_n} n-E(X;|X|<n)\overset{p}\to 0$. Further generalizations (for weaker assumptions) depend behavior of $E(X;|X|<n)$ (if tends to a constant, it gets washed out). It seems like there is very little mileage from redefining the mean to principal value while something as simple as SLLN requires finite mean, not just principle value.

Comment: @whuber: I find the arguments of my answer more persuasive (surprise!), and they comes from modeling: models (like the cauchy) are approximations, real life random variables are practically bounded, so if we modify the model by introducing some (largely arbitrary ) bounds, we want that results do not change too much. If we accept tha Cauchy to have mean of zero, that will not hold.

Comment: @Kjetil Thank you.  I suspect you and I might have some differences of opinion concerning the uses of models in statistics, but despite that I cannot help but agree with the particular point you make: namely, that we must be cautious when employing any model that is sensitive to behavior that is unrealistically far out in the tails.  BTW, I liked your answer originally and already upvoted it :-).

Comment: Does the non convergence apply to the other t-Student distributions (excluding normal, of course)?

Answer (score 23):

The Cauchy distribution is best thought of as the uniform distribution on a unit circle, so it would be surprising if averaging made sense. Suppose $f$ were some kind of "averaging function". That is, suppose that, for each finite subset $X$ of the unit circle, $f(X)$ was a point of the unit circle. Clearly, $f$ has to be "unnatural". More precisely $f$ cannot be equivariant with respect to rotations. To obtain the Cauchy distribution in its more usual, but less revealing, form, project the unit circle onto the x-axis from (0,1), and use this projection to transfer the uniform distribution on the circle to the x-axis.

To understand why the mean doesn't exist, think of x as a function on the unit circle. It's quite easy to find an infinite number of disjoint arcs on the unit circle, such that, if one of the arcs has length d, then x > 1/4d on that arc. So each of these disjoint arcs contributes more than 1/4 to the mean, and the total contribution from these arcs is infinite. We can do the same thing again, but with x < -1/4d, with a total contribution minus infinity. These intervals could be displayed with a diagram, but can one make diagrams for Cross Validated?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @DavidEpstein. You can make images w/ your preferred software & upload them into your answer by clicking the little picture icon (to launch the wizard) above the answer field. Unfortunately however, you need >=10 rep to do so. I'm sure you'll have that soon enough; in the interim, if you can post the image anywhere else on the internet & post a link to it in your answer, a higher rep user can fetch it & post it for you.

Comment: I wasn't aware of Cauchy being interpreted as a uniform on a circle but it certainly makes sense. A topological argument shows that there can be no continuous function on a circle that has the properties of an averaging function.

Comment: @DavidEpstein I've also read [your answer in the other post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/233950/131145). The stereographic projection is really nice. In comparison, can you comment on why the equally valid radial projection of a semicircle doesn't imply the mean to be well-defined? Namely, $U \sim \mathrm{Unif}[0,1]$, then $X \equiv \tan\left( \pi( U - \frac12 ) \right)$ is standard Cauchy. Geometrically this is the basic fact that an inscribed angle is always half of its corresponding central angle.

Comment: Actually in terms of the physical model of a light source, the semicircle picture is more appropriate, since it's not immediately clear why the Huygens' principle would give you a stereographic projection.

Answer (score 11):

The mean  or expected value of some random variable $X$ is a Lebesgue integral defined over some probability measure $P$:
$$EX=\int XdP$$

The nonexistence of the mean of Cauchy random variable just means that the integral of Cauchy r.v. does not exist. This is because the tails of Cauchy distribution are heavy tails (compare to the tails of normal distribution).
However, nonexistence of expected value does not forbid the existence of other functions of a Cauchy random variable.

Comment: The tails are "heavy" in the sense that they do not decay fast enough in either direction to cause the integral to converge. This concept has nothing to do with normal distributions (or any reference distribution).

Comment: Yes, thanks for this correction. I have not intended to imply any rigour connection between heavy tails and normal distribution. However, I think that comparing normal distribution (with light tails) and heavy-tailed distribution visually makes (not always) a bit easier to grasp the concept of the "heavy" tails.

Answer (score 6):

Here is more of a visual explanation.  (For those of us that are math challenged.). Take a cauchy distributed random number generator and try averaging the resulting values.  Here is a good page on a function for this.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484395/how-to-generate-a-cauchy-random-variable
You will find that the "spikiness" of the random values cause it to get larger as you go instead of smaller.  Hence it has no mean.

Comment: Logged in just to give you an upvote on this. While the math checks out, I love the intuition here as to what it pragmatically means!

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the excellent answers, I will make some comments about why the nonconvergence of the integral is relevant for statistical practice. As others have mentioned, if we allowed the principal value to be a "mean" then the slln are not anymore valid!  Apart from this, think about the implications  of the fact that , in practice, all models are approximations. Specifically, the Cauchy distribution is a model for an unbounded random variable. In practice, random variables are bounded, but the bounds are often vague and uncertain. Using unbounded models is  way to alleviate that, it makes unnecessary the introduction of unsure (and often unnatural) bounds into the models.  But for this to make sense, important aspects of the problem should not be affected. That means that, if we were to introduce bounds, that should not alter in important ways the model. But when the integral is nonconvergent that does not happen!  The model is unstable, in the sense that the expectation of the RV would depend on the largely arbitrary bounds. (In applications, there is not necessarily any reason to make the bounds symmetric!)

For this reason, it is better to say the integral is divergent than saying it is "infinite", the last being close to imply some definite value when no exists! A more thorough discussion is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94402/what-is-the-difference-between-finite-and-infinite-variance/100161#100161).