# Changing only one point of a discrete distribution to maximize variance augmentation

Tags: probability, variance, discrete-data, bounds

X has a discrete distribution with support $x1, x2, ...$ in $ {]}0,1{[}$. You have the right to change only one of the $xi$ to lead to the highest increase in variance (or, at least, a systematic increase in variance). How do you describe this change?

*Background of the question*: I was trying to describe variance-increasing transformations to prove [Popoviciu's inequality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45588/variance-of-a-bounded-random-variable): X has maximal variance when it takes only two values, 0 and 1, with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. I hoped I could find a proof by defining a suite of transformations leading to such a distribution and increasing variance every time. With this in mind, I initially thought of this function, changing $xp$ only, as described:

\begin{equation}
f(xi)= 
 \begin{cases} 
      x & \text{if }i \neq  p \\
      1 & \text{if }E(X) < \frac{1}{2} \text{ & } i = p \\
      0 & \text{if }E(X) > \frac{1}{2} \text{ & } i = p\\
   \end{cases}
\]
\end{equation}

However, this does not increase the variance every time if xp is chosen randomly...

Comment: I would guess taking the value closest to the mean and moving it as far away from the mean as possible would be a good starting point.   If the probabilities aren't equal, you'd want to involve them in the choice of which point to move as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice! Denoting the support of random variable X with {x1, x2, ...}, the function I found is defined with, for each p:
S(xi) = xi if i is not p (this means we only change one element indexed p at a time).
S(xp) = 1 if E(X) < x(p) * [1 + f(xp)] / 2 ; 
S(xp) = 0 otherwise

The way I found this function is by writing Var(S(X)) - Var(X) as a function of S(xp), E(X) and xp, and then by defining S for Var(S(X)) to be always greater than Var(X).