Maximum Variance of 3 Numbers in a Range
If I have a set of 3 numbers $(x, y, z)$, all between $A$ and $B$ inclusive (e.g. $A = 0 $ and $B = 1$), what would the maximum variance be? Intuition says it would be (e.g.) $0.1666...$, given by $x = 0, y = 0.5, z = 1$. Is there a general formula for this?

Welcome to CV, Alex.  Have you considered searching this site?  You can find closely related answers are already posted, such as those at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45588, and they can provide useful insight into your question and its generalizations and applications.

Variance is maximized in your case by $(0,0,1)$ or $(0,1,1)$ and is $1/3$.
In general, have half your data points at $A$, the other half at $B$, and if $n$ is odd, pick any extreme for the data point left out, it does not matter.
For cases like this, simulation is very helpful. Simply simulate 10,000 triplets (or $n$-lets) of data and pick out the one with maximal variance. This is two lines in R:
> sims <- replicate(10000,runif(3))
> sims[,which.max(apply(sims,2,var))]
[1] 0.996247644 0.003987293 0.979907348


Shouldn't the variance be 2/9 instead of 1/3?

@CamilleGontier perhaps you should show us your calculations?

+1. But this answer can be misleading because it reports variance estimates as if these were data.  The actual variance of the distribution determined by your solution is $2/9$ as Camille Gontier claims (cc @mdewey).

The variance of $x$, $y$, and $z$ is $\frac{2}{9}(x^2+y^2+z^2 - xy -xz -yz)$. Setting its partial derivatives to $0$ yields
$$
2x -y -z =0
$$
$$
2y -x -z =0
$$
$$
2z -x -y =0
$$
and hence $x=y=z$, which is a minimum since in that case the variance will be $0$. The maximum is thus somewhere on the boundary conditions. You can explore them via numerical optimization, or simply try them by hand since you only have 3 variables. The maximum is thus indeed reached for $(0,1,1)$, or symmetrically for $(0,0,1)$, and is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{3} \left( (0-\frac{1}{3})^2 + (0-\frac{1}{3})^2 + (1-\frac{1}{3})^2 \right) = \frac{2}{9}
$$

+1. But the situation can be analyzed much more simply by setting two of the variables to $0$ and $1$ at the outset, reducing it to a single-variable problem (a quadratic) whose two solutions are immediate.
