# Does non-zero correlation imply dependence?

Tags: correlation, independence

We know of the fact that zero correlation does not imply independence. I am interested in whether a non-zero correlation implies dependence - i.e. if $\text{Corr}(X,Y)\ne0$ for some random variables $X$ and $Y$, can we say in general that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) \ne f_X(x) f_Y(y)$?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, because

$$\text{Corr}(X,Y)\ne0 \Rightarrow \text{Cov}(X,Y)\ne0$$

$$\Rightarrow E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) \ne 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow \int \int xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy -\int xf_X(x) dx\int yf_Y(y)dy \ne 0$$

$$\Rightarrow \int \int xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy -\int \int xyf_X(x) f_Y(y)dxdy \ne 0$$

$$\Rightarrow  \int \int xy \big[f_{X,Y}(x,y) -f_X(x) f_Y(y)\big]dxdy \ne 0$$

which would be impossible if $f_{X,Y}(x,y) -f_X(x) f_Y(y) =0,\;\; \forall \{x,y\}$. So

$$\text{Corr}(X,Y)\ne0 \Rightarrow \exists \{x,y\}:f_{X,Y}(x,y) \ne f_X(x) f_Y(y)$$

Question: what happens with random variables that have no densities?

Comment: Alecos, I have a dumb question. What does the fancy arrow mean in, e.g., line 1? I imagine something like "imply," but I'm uncertain.

Comment: @user777 You mean $\Rightarrow$? Indeed, it means "implies".

Comment: The reason to only use the implication arrow in informal argument: is the implication arrow left or right associative?

Comment: `\implies` produces $\implies$ which looks better than `\rightarow` which produces $\Rightarrow$.

Answer (score 18):

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote random variables such that $E[X^2]$ and $E[Y^2]$
are finite.  Then, $E[XY]$, $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ all are finite.

Restricting our attention to such random variables, let
 $A$ denote the statement that $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables
and $B$ the statement that $X$ and $Y$ are *uncorrelated* random variables,
that is, $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$.  Then we know that $A$ implies $B$, that is,
independent random variables are uncorrelated random variables. Indeed,
one *definition* of independent random variables is that 
$E[g(X)h(Y)]$ equals $E[g(X)]E[h(Y)]$ for all measurable functions $g(\cdot)$
and $h(\cdot)$).  This is usually
expressed as
$$A \implies B.$$
But $A \implies B$ is logically equivalent to $\neg B \implies \neg A$, that is,

> *correlated* random variables are *dependent* random variables.

If $E[XY]$, $E[X]$ or $E[Y]$ are not finite or do not exist, then it
is not possible to say whether $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated or not
in the classical meaning of uncorrelated random variables being those
for which $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$. For example,
$X$ and $Y$ could be independent Cauchy random variables (for 
which [the mean does not exist](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/36027/6633)). 
Are they uncorrelated random variables in the classical sense?

Comment: The nice thing about this answer is that it applies whether or not the random variables in question admit a density function, as opposed to other answers on this thread. This is true due to the fact that expectations can be defined with Stieltjes integrals using the CDF, with no mention of the density.

Answer (score 3):

Here a purely logical proof. If $A\rightarrow B$ then necessarily $\neg B \rightarrow \neg A$, as the two are equivalent. Thus if $\neg B$ then $\neg A$. Now replace $A$ with independence and $B$ with correlation.

Think about a statement "if volcano erupts there are going to be damages". Now think about a case where there are no damages. Clearly a volcano didn't erupt or we would have a condtradicition.

Similarly, think about a case "If independent $X,Y$, then non-correlated $X,Y$". Now, consider the case where $X,Y$ are correlated. Clearly they can't be independent, for if they were, they would also be correlated. Thus conclude dependence.

Comment: If you will read my answer carefully, you will see that I too used the argument that you have made in your answer, namely that $A \implies B$ is the same as $\neq  B \implies \neg A$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Edited to reflect that.