# Covariance of $X$ and $M$

Tags: covariance, finance

I was wondering how we compute the covariance of $r$<sub>$x$</sub> and $r$<sub>$m$</sub>. Here is the problem:

We know that:

For stock $X:
E(r_x) = 0.21$, and $Stdev(r_x) = 0.15$.

For stock $Y:
E(r_y) = 0.15$, and $Stdev(r_y) = 0.09$.

and $Corr(r_x, r_y) = 1/3$.

For market portfolio $M:
E(r_m) = 0.17$, $Stdev(r_m) = 0.09$,

$W_m = W_x + W_Y = 1$, and $W_x=1/3$ and $W_y=2/3$.

How do I compute $Cov(r_x, r_m)$?

M is the market portfolio, and W<sub>i</sub> is the weight of stock i. E(r<sub>i</sub>) is the expected return for stock i.

Thanks :)

Comment: What are $W_x, W_y$? What's the difference between $X$ and $r_x$?

Comment: Please explain what these various symbols mean and how they are all inter-related: $X, r_x,W_x,Y,W_y,r_y,M,W_m,r_m.$

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes, I've just added a few notes on the variables. Hope this helps and thanks.

Comment: For answers to the edited question, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184998 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721 (among many that give correct formulas).

Comment: thank you @whuber, found the answer :)