# Variance of a vector-valued random variable along a unit vector

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, moments

Let $X$ be a vector-valued random variable with variance $\mathbb{V}[X] < \infty$. How is the variance of $X$ along a unit-vector $\hat{v}$ defined? Can we say that in general it is $\hat{v}^\top \mathbb{V}[X]\hat{v}$?

> **Example**: For $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ with $\mathbb{V}[X] = \Sigma$ then the variance along the unit vector is $\mathbb{V}_{\hat{v}}[X]
>  = \hat{v}^\top \Sigma \hat{v}$.

Comment: How is the variance of *any* vector defined?

Comment: @whuber I'd say the variance of a vector-valued random variable is $\mathbb{V}[x] = \mathbb{E}[(x-\mathbb{E}[x]) (x - \mathbb{E}[x])^\top]$ based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#For_vector-valued_random_variables)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the variance along a unit vector? Do you mean $\mathbb{V}\bigg[
\vec v^TX\vec v
\bigg]?$

Comment: @Dave I am trying to understand how to write it formally, so I am not sure yet. Essentially I would like to see the variance of that random variable when projected in that direction, I suppose

Comment: You would have to have a multivariate random variable to project it, right?

Comment: @Dave Yes absolutely, it's a vector-valued random variable. I will make it clear in the question

Comment: Immagine you have a diagonal 2D Gaussian with variances $1.0$ and $5.0$ respectively. Then the variance along $(1,0)$ is just $1.0$ and along $(0,1)$ is $5.0$. How does this generalise to non gaussian and larger dimensional problems?

Comment: When you apply your definition to the random variable $v^\prime X,$ you immediately obtain the formula in terms of $\Sigma:$ this is the *bilinearity* property of variance, following directly from the linearity of expectation. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184998 for an elementary (matrix-free) exposition.