Beta hat conditional variance - Hansen Econometrics
I'm working through Econometrics by Bruce Hansen, and I'm not sure how to get to his conditional variance proof on page 90.
Hansen says:
For any $n \times r$ matrix $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{X})$:
$\text{var}(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{X}) = \text{var}(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{e}|\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}$, where $D=\text{diag}(\sigma_1^2, ..., \sigma^2_n)$.
Why is this the case? I can see this step, but I'm not sure how to justify it from the full definition: $\text{var}(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{e}|\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{A}^T\text{var}(\mathbf{e}|\mathbf{X})\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}$.
I.e. how do I get there with this: $\text{var}(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{X}) = \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{Z} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{X}])(\mathbf{Z} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{X}])^T|\mathbf{X}], \mathbf{\hat\beta} = \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}$
I tried but I kept on getting matrix dimensions that don't match up.

Don't do it that way.  This result is merely invoking the bilinearity property and the definition of matrix multiplication.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721

This step uses the bilinearity property of the variance operator.  For any random vector $\mathbf{e}$ and any conformable constant matrix $\mathbf{A}$ you can derive the general bilinearity rule:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e})
&= \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e})) (\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e}))^\text{T}] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e})) ((\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e})^\text{T}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e})^\text{T})] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e})) (\mathbf{e}^\text{T} \mathbf{A}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{e}^\text{T} \mathbf{A}))] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbf{e}-\mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbb{E}(\mathbf{e})) (\mathbf{e}^\text{T} \mathbf{A}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{e})^\text{T} \mathbf{A})] \\[6pt] 
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{A}^\text{T} (\mathbf{e}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{e})) (\mathbf{e}^\text{T}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{e})^\text{T}) \mathbf{A}] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{e}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{e})) (\mathbf{e}-\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{e}))^\text{T}] \mathbf{A} \\[6pt]
&= \mathbf{A}^\text{T} \mathbb{V}(\mathbf{e}) \mathbf{A}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
(Note that in this working I have removed the conditioning element and just assumed that $\mathbf{A}$ is a constant.  This simplifies the presentation and is analogous to your situation once you bring in the conditioning.)  In the working in Hansen (2014) (p. 90) the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is constant under the conditioning statement and the variance of the random vector is $\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{e}) = \mathbf{D} = \text{diag}(\sigma_1^2,...,\sigma_n^2)$ which gives the result of interest to you.

+1. But having mentioned bilinearity, you should feel free to skip the six intervening steps!

Thanks!  I guess I'm proving the bilinearity rather than just relying on asserting it.

You could just reference https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184998, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721, or even https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18200/919 ;-).

Exactly what I was looking for, thanks
