# Can someone provide a proof for this theorem that was used in the proof of law of large number?

Tags: probability, random-variable, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ be $i.i.d.$ with finite mean $\mu$.

Then let $Y_i=X_i1_{\{|X_i|<i\}}$

There will be only finitely many terms such that $Y_i\neq X_i$

While that lecture notes did not provide proof, it hinted it is related to Borel–Cantelli.

What is the proof for the statement

Comment: What is $k$?  After all, when $k=0$ (or, more generally, when $\Pr(|X_i|\lt k)=0$) the statement evidently can be false, so there must be some kind of restriction on $k.$

Comment: Sorry, that is a mistype, there is no k, there is only i

Comment: You can find the proof in any strong law proofs of which there’s a ton in literature and textbooks, e.g. see p 57 here http://math.mit.edu/~sheffield/2016175/Lecture6.pdf

Comment: @Aksakal Indeed, and this is the first lemma used for the general proof, which I don't know how to prove

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to apply [the Borel-Cantelli lemma,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) that means you expect to show that the sum of all the chances of the events $Y_i\ne X_i$ is finite.  Somehow this must be derivable from the assumptions--and about the only useful assumption available is that the common distribution has finite mean.  What is the connection between these statements?

Notice that $Y_i \ne X_i$ is equivalent to $|X_i| \ge i.$  There's no problem working with $|X_i|$ instead of $X_i$ because

1. The independence of the $X_i$ [implies the independence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94876/919) of the $|X_i|.$
2. Because the $X_i$ are identically distributed, the $|X_i|$ are identically distributed.
3. The mean of $X_i$ is defined and finite [if and only if](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117396/919) the mean of $|X_i|$ is defined and finite.

What's the connection between the mean of a variable and the chances that it's large?  The answer lies in the "tail probability expectation formula" (see the reference or consult [Expectation of a function of a random variable from CDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222478)),

$$\mathbb{E}(|X_j|) = \int_0^\infty \Pr(|X_j| \gt x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

for any $j.$

To relate this to $\Pr(|X_i|\ge i)$ we can break this integral into pieces at the integers $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ and underestimate its argument a little in each piece because the $X_i$ are identically distributed.  Specifically, for any $x\lt i,$

> $$\Pr(|X_j| \gt x) \ge \Pr(|X_j| \ge i) = \Pr(X_i \ge i).$$

This is the key step in the following derivation, which begins with observation $(3)$ that $|X_j|$ has finite expectation:

$$\eqalign{
\infty \gt \int_0^\infty \Pr(|X_j| \gt x)\,\mathrm{d}x &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{i-1}^i \Pr(|X_j| \gt x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&\ge\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{i-1}^i \Pr(|X_i| \ge i)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \Pr(|X_i| \ge i)\,\int_{i-1}^i \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \Pr(|X_i| \ge i).
}$$

That's the condition for applying Borel-Cantelli, *QED.*

#### Reference

Ambrose Lo, *Demystifying the Integrated Tail Probability Expectation Formula.*  The American Statistician Volume 73, Number 4, November 2019, pp 367-374.

Comment: Thanks, to be precise so it also works for discrete RV, the inequality can also be rewritten as $\geq \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}Pr(|X_i|\geq i)$

Comment: Thank you.  I have taken care of that in an edited version of the derivation.