# confidence intervals of a biological assay

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, bioinformatics

Given my work on ICeChIP (a biological assay that measures the binding of one, two, or more proteins along the genome)

https://github.com/shah-rohan/icechip/blob/master/Scripts/computeHMDandError

I would appreciate to have the answer to the question :

given two proteins A and B, that bind together in 100000 locations, the binding strength of each protein A and B on in **location (i)** is denoted by **values a(i) or b(i)**. The assay also provides a calibration number "cal".

[image]

Why the 95 confidence interval of binding strength of protein A has been calculated as :

```
100 / cal * sqrt (( a/ (b^2) + (a^2) / (b ^3)) * 1.96
```

Bogdan

Comment: Maybe try asking this on the Bioinformatics StackExchange.

Comment: Can you say something more about `cal`?

Comment: Hi Peter, and Dario, thank you for your comments. I shall take formula for granted at this moment. as it has been published in a methods articles. I have asked a while ago the authors why they have chosen this formula, however, I have not received any reply.                                                                              
https://www.cell.com/molecular-cell/fulltext/S1097-2765(15)00304-4

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41596-019-0218-7

https://www.cell.com/molecular-cell/fulltext/S1097-2765(15)00304-4

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41596-019-0218-7

Answer (score 1):

The formula in question is a simple application of the approximate formula for the variance of a ratio of uncorrelated variables. In this case, it's the ratio of immunoprecipitated (IP'd) DNA to the total input DNA over specific regions of the genome, in
[chromatin immunoprecipitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatin_immunoprecipitation) (ChIP) experiments.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/415195/28500) provides a general approximate form for the variance of the ratio of two uncorrelated variables $X$ and $Y$:

$$\sigma_{X/Y}^2 \approx \sigma_{X}^2 \cdot \frac{1}{\mu_Y^2} + \sigma_{Y}^2 \cdot \frac{\mu_X^2}{\mu_Y^4}.$$

where $\mu_X$, $\mu_Y$, $\sigma_{X}^2$, $\sigma_{Y}^2$ are their means and variances.

In ChIP experiments one effectively counts the number of input and IP'd DNA fragments, so it's reasonable to assume that both are Poisson-distributed, with variances equal to their means. With $X$ and $Y$ both Poisson-distributed, the above simplifies to:

$$\sigma_{X/Y}^2 \approx \mu_{X} \cdot \frac{1}{\mu_Y^2} + \mu_{Y} \cdot \frac{\mu_X^2}{\mu_Y^4} =  \frac{\mu_{X}}{\mu_Y^2} + \frac{\mu_X^2}{\mu_Y^3}.$$

The square root of that is the (approximate) standard deviation of the ratio, and 1.96 is the factor for converting the standard deviation to 95% confidence intervals under a normal approximation. Substitute your $a$ and $b$ for $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ and we're almost there.

The remaining `cal` value comes from the internal calibration standard used in the [ICeChIP method](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molcel.2015.04.022), to correct for antibody affinity. That gives a "Barcode IP enrichment"; those who developed the method "assume that standard deviation of Barcode IP enrichment is negligible" and thus "Barcode IP enrichment" can simply appear as a multiplicative factor in the CI calculation. The `cal` factor in your equation is the inverse of that "Barcode IP enrichment."

*A few more details on [ICeChIP](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molcel.2015.04.022)*

ChIP examines the fractions of different DNA regions associated with specific forms of proteins involved in gene regulation. DNA is broken down into short pieces and an antibody against a specific form of a protein is used to "pull down" associated DNA. The specific immunoprecipitated (IP'd) DNA is identified by polymerase chain reaction or by high-throughput DNA sequencing.

One would like to know the actual fraction of the input DNA that is associated with the protein in question. The `IP/input` ratio provides a first approximation. The antibody, however, is not completely effective at "pulling down" all of the associated DNA. The [ICeChIP method](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molcel.2015.04.022) uses internal standards to correct for the antibody's "pull down"  effectiveness. The `cal` factor in the OP's formula is that correction factor. It's the inverse of the "Barcode IP enrichment" in a formula on the 21st page of [Supplemental Material](https://www.cell.com/cms/10.1016/j.molcel.2015.04.022/attachment/0653c03c-3d62-4771-a5b7-ef7bd63e2349/mmc1.pdf) for the [ICeChIP paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molcel.2015.04.022).

---

Adrian T. Grzybowski, Zhonglei Chen, Alexander J. Ruthenburg,
"[Calibrating ChIP-Seq with Nucleosomal Internal Standards to Measure Histone Modification Density Genome Wide](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molcel.2015.04.022)." *Mol Cell* 58: 886-899, 2015.

Comment: This is a very profound explanation ! Thank you for sharing your extensive knowledge !