# What is the expected value of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$?

Tags: covariance, random-variable, expected-value

I am trying to find the expected value of

$\displaystyle E\Bigg[\frac{X}{X+Y}\Bigg]$.

I started with writing

$\displaystyle E\Bigg[\frac{X}{X+Y}\Bigg] = 
               E\Bigg[X\cdot\frac{1}{X+Y}\Bigg]
$.

I then noticed that

$E[XY] = \text{cov}(X,Y) + E[X]E[Y]$

which follows from the definition of covariance. So, I have

$\displaystyle E\Bigg[X\cdot\frac{1}{X+Y}\Bigg] =
               \text{cov}\Big(X, \frac{1}{X+Y}\Big)+E[X]E\Bigg[\frac{1}{X+Y}\Bigg]$

but I don't know how to proceed from here.

The variables $X$ and $Y$ are both normally distributed and positively correlated.

Comment: Finding the expectation requires knowing the bivariate distribution of $(X,Y)$.  What are you assuming it is?

Comment: Bivariate normal.

Comment: Assuming you mean $(X,Y)$ has a binormal distribution, you could equally well ask for $E[X/Y]$ because $(X,X+Y)$ will be binormal, too.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157557 is essentially the same question.  (IMHO the comments there are more useful than the answers, because the question was unfortunately posed in a way that invites invalid mathematical manipulation.)  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36027 is also relevant.

Comment: To add to whuber's comment, suppose that jointly normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ have identical marginal distributions (the correlation is not relevant). Then the following _invalid_ mathematical manipulation gives us that $$E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] + E\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right] = E\left[\frac{X+Y}{X+Y}\right]=E[1] = 1$$ and so since _symmetry_ allows us to infer that $E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] = E\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right]$, we easily determine that $\displaystyle E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] = \frac{1}{2}$. What could be easier? So now figure out where the calculations went astray...

Answer (score 5):

If $(X,Y)$ is binormal, then so is $(X,Z) = (X,X+Y)$.  The ratio $X/Z$ is the tangent of the slope of the line through the origin and the point $(Z,X)$.  When $X$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated with zero means, [it is well known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalRatioDistribution.html) (and easy to compute) that $X/Z$ has a Cauchy distribution.  Cauchy distributions have no expectations.  This should lead us to suspect $X/Z$ might not have a mean, either.  Let's see whether it does nor not.

For any angle $0 \lt \theta \lt \pi/2$, consider the event

$$E_\theta = \{(Z,X)\,|\, X \ge Z\cot(\theta\}.$$

This is of interest because its probability is the chance that $X/Z$ exceeds $\cot(\theta)$: the [*survival function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) of $X/Z$.  It carries all the information of the distribution function of $X/Z$.

$E_\theta$ is a (closed) cone in the plane consisting of all points on all lines making an angle of $\theta$ or less to the right of the vertical ($X$) axis. Let's underestimate the probability of $E_\theta$.  To do so, we will work in polar coordinates.  Consider any possible radius $\rho$.  Among all points of this radius within the set $E_\theta$, the density $f$ of $(Z,X)$ will achieve a minimum value $f_\theta(\rho)$.  This minimum must be nonzero provided the density does not degenerate.  (More about this possibility later.)  Use this to bound the probability

$$\eqalign{
\Pr(E_\theta) &= \int_{\pi/2-\theta}^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty f(\phi,\rho) \rho d\rho d\phi  \\
&\ge \int_{\pi/2-\theta}^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty \rho f_\theta(\rho) d\rho d\phi \\
&=\theta \int_0^\infty \rho f_\theta(\rho) d\rho \\
&= C(\theta) \theta
}$$

where I have written $C(\theta)$ for the integral, which is some positive number depending on $\theta$.  Moreover, for $0\lt\theta\lt\pi/2$, $C(\theta)$ has a nonzero lower bound $C \gt 0$.

By definition, the expectation of $X/Z$ is the sum of two parts: one integral for the positive part when $X/Z \ge 0$ and another for the negative part when $X/Z \lt 0$.  Let's tackle the positive part.  For *any* positive random variable $W$ with distribution function $F$, integration by parts shows its expectation equals the integral of its survival function $1-F$, since

$$\mathbb{E}(W) = \int_0^\infty w dF(w) = (w(1-F(w))|_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty (1-F(w)) dw = \int_0^\infty (1-F(w)) dw.$$

Applying this to $W = X/Z$ and substituting $w=\cot(\phi)$ gives for the positive part of the integral

$$\eqalign{
\int_0^\infty (1 - F(w)) dw &= \int_0^{\pi/2} (1 - F(\cot(\phi))) \csc^2(\phi) d\phi \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \Pr(E_\phi) \csc^2(\phi) d\phi \\
&\ge C \int_0^\theta \phi \csc^2(\phi) d\phi \\
&\gt C \int_0^\theta \frac{d\phi}{\phi}. 
}$$

(The final inequality is a simple consequence of the well-known inequalities $0 \lt \sin(\phi) \lt \phi$ for $0 \lt \phi \lt \pi$, which upon taking the $-2$ power gives $\csc^2(\phi) \gt 1/\phi^2$.)

For any $\theta \gt 0$, the last term is a divergent integral, because for $0\lt \epsilon$,

$$\int_0^\theta \frac{d\phi}{\phi} \gt \int_\epsilon^\theta \frac{d\phi}{\phi} = \log(\theta) - \log(\epsilon) \to  \infty$$

as $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$.

Consequently, **the positive part of the expectation does not exist.**  It is immediate that the expectation of $X/W$ does not exist, either.

We left behind one exception to consider: when $X/Z$ is supported on a line passing through the origin, this argument breaks down (because then the density *can* equal zero--and in fact is zero for almost all $\theta$).  In this degenerate case, $X/Z$ reduces to a constant--equal to tangent of the slope of that line--and obviously that constant is its expectation.  *This is the only such situation in which $X/Z$ has an expectation.*

Answer (score 5):

This is a follow-up to whuber's answer, and posted as a separate answer
because it is too long for a comment.

Lest people think that it is the bivariate normality 
of $X$ and $Y$ that is causing the problem, it is worth emphasizing that if $W$ is a continuous random variable whose *density is nonzero on an open interval containing the origin,* then $E\left[\frac 1W\right]$ does not exist. Since $\frac 1w$ diverges to $\pm\infty$ as $w$ approaches $0$, the integral for 
$E\left[\frac 1W\right]$, which is of the form
$$E\left[\frac 1W\right]=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac 1w f_W(w)\,\mathrm dw
+ \int_0^{-\infty} \frac 1w f_W(w)\,\mathrm dw\tag{1}$$
is undefined because both integrals on the right side of
$(1)$ diverge and the
right side of $(1)$ is of the form $\infty-\infty$ (which is undefined).