# What is the expected value of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ when $X,Y > 0$?

Tags: expected-value, ratio

I've read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161461/what-is-the-expected-value-of-fracxxy) question (and suggested links) which poses the same question assuming $X,Y$ are bivariate standard normal. Since the support includes $0$, the expectation does not exist. This makes perfect sense.

I'm interested instead in the situation where $X,Y$ are still normally distributed, but bounded away from zero (say the support is truncated at some $\delta>0$). They possess different means and variance, however. If it helps, $X,Y$ are independent, though I'm curious about any insight to the general case.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can say without any information on the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ other that they're always positive.

Comment: Okay, I've supposed that $X,Y$ are normally distributed for the sake of discussion. Though in my original problem $X$ and $Y$ are both squared normals; I thought that level of detail might detract from the discussion a bit.

Comment: That level of detail (both squared normals) may make it possible to answer the question, because it's such a special situation.  The case you posit has an aura of artificiality and amounts, as far as one can tell, only to an integration exercise.

Comment: You might have to just get symbolic results only for special cases.  For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent normals with variances $\sigma_X^2$ and $\sigma_Y^2$, then the mean of $X/(X+Y)$ given that $X>0$ and $Y>0$ is $\frac{2\sigma_X \left(\sigma_Y \log \left(\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}\right)+\sigma_X \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}\right)\right)\right)}{\pi  \left(\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2\right)}$.

Comment: Sorry.  I forgot to include that $X$ and $Y$ also have zero means in that special case.

Comment: @norvia If $X>0$ and $Y>0$, then $X+Y > X$, so we can also say that $\frac{X}{X+Y} < 1$.

Answer (score 10):

If $X$ and $Y$ are positive random variables *both with finite means*, then $\frac{X}{X+Y} \in (0,1)$ and so $E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] \in (0,1)$ also. Similarly, $\frac{Y}{X+Y} \in (0,1)$ and so $E\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right] \in (0,1)$ also.
Then, as noted in my comment on the question cited by the OP, we can write
$$E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] + E\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right] 
= E\left[\frac{X+Y}{X+Y}\right] = 1$$
and the above calculation is perfectly valid here whereas it was incorrect in what I had written in my comment on the previous question.  If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed, then symmetry allows to claim that $E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] = E\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right]$ and we get that
$$E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right] = E\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right] = \frac 12.$$
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent but not identically distributed, then we have to work harder. We need to calculate
$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x+y} f_X(x)f_Y(y) \,\mathrm dx \,
 \mathrm dy$$
(assuming $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables with densities $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ respectively). This is an exercise in integration.

Comment: Ah, sadly they have different means/variances! I have clarified the question...

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**

Suppose the problem is described as follows:  $X$ and $Y$ have a bivariate normal distribution with respective parameters $\mu_X$, $\mu_Y$, $\sigma_X$, $\sigma_Y$, and $\rho$ and it is desired to find the mean of $R=X/(X+Y)$ given that $X>0$ and $Y>0$, then using *Mathematica* I was only able to find a symbolic result for $E(R|X>0, Y>0)$ when $\mu_X=\mu_Y=0$.  Short of that there is a symbolic result for the density of $R$ given $X>0$ and $Y>0$ which then numerical integration can be used.  Both of these results match means found from random sampling.

**Case 1:  $\mu_X=\mu_Y=0$**

```
distxy = BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {\[Sigma]x, \[Sigma]y}, \[Rho]];
distPositive = TruncatedDistribution[{{0, \[Infinity]}, {0, \[Infinity]}}, distxy];
dR = TransformedDistribution[x/(x + y), {x, y} \[Distributed] distPositive, 
   Assumptions -> {\[Sigma]x > 0, \[Sigma]y > 0, \[Mu]x \[Element] Reals, \[Mu]y \[Element] Reals}];
pdf00 = PDF[dR, z]
```

The result for the pdf is

[image: pdf of conditional ratio]

I don't know why but the first line of the result is wrong because it doesn't integrate to 1.  (And while it looks like it involves imaginary numbers, the resulting density is real and positive.  I've written *Mathematica* about it not integrating to 1.  It turns out aht the second line of the equation does work for all values of $\rho$.)

So the pdf for $-1\lt \rho < 1$ is

$$\frac{2 \sqrt{1-\rho ^2} \sigma_X \sigma_Y}{\left(2 \sin ^{-1}(\rho )+\pi \right) \left(\sigma_Y^2 z^2+2 \rho  \sigma_X \sigma_Y (z-1) z+\sigma_X^2 (z-1)^2\right)}$$

The mean is found with

```
Integrate[z (2 Sqrt[1 - \[Rho]^2] \[Sigma]x \[Sigma]y)/(((-1 + z)^2 \[Sigma]x^2 + 
  2 (-1 + z) z \[Rho] \[Sigma]x \[Sigma]y + z^2 \[Sigma]y^2) (\[Pi] + 2 ArcSin[\Rho]])),
  {z, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {\[Sigma]x > 0, \[Sigma]y > 0, -1 < \[Rho] < 1}]
```

and results in

$$\frac{2 \sigma_X \left(\sqrt{1-\rho ^2} \sigma_Y \log \left(\frac{\text{$\sigma $y}}{\sigma_X}\right)+(\rho  \sigma_Y+\sigma_X) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho  \sigma_X+\sigma_Y}{\sqrt{1-\rho ^2} \sigma_X}\right)+(\rho  \sigma_Y+\sigma_X) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho  \sigma_Y+\sigma_X}{\sqrt{1-\rho ^2} \sigma_Y}\right)\right)}{\left(2 \sin ^{-1}(\rho )+\pi \right) \left(2 \rho  \sigma_X \sigma_Y+\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2\right)}$$

As a partial check on this consider finding the mean from random sampling:

```
(* Set parameters *)
parms = {\[Sigma]x -> 1, \[Sigma]y -> 3, \[Rho] -> -6/7};

(* Theoretical mean *)
(2 \[Sigma]x ((\[Sigma]x + \[Rho] \[Sigma]y) ArcTan[(\[Rho] \[Sigma]x + \[Sigma]y)/
  (Sqrt[1 - \[Rho]^2] \[Sigma]x)] + (\[Sigma]x + \[Rho] \[Sigma]y) ArcTan[(\[Sigma]x + 
  \[Rho] \[Sigma]y)/(Sqrt[1 - \[Rho]^2] \[Sigma]y)] + 
  Sqrt[1 - \[Rho]^2] \[Sigma]y Log[\[Sigma]y/\[Sigma]x]))/
  ((\[Sigma]x^2 + 2 \[Rho] \[Sigma]x \[Sigma]y + \[Sigma]y^2) (\[Pi] + 2 ArcSin[\Rho]])) 
  /. parms // N
(* 0.322394 *)

(* Mean from random sampling *)
n = 1000000;
distxy = BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {\[Sigma]x, \[Sigma]y}, \[Rho]];
distPositive = 
  TruncatedDistribution[{{0, \[Infinity]}, {0, \[Infinity]}}, distxy];
xy = RandomVariate[distPositive /. parms, n];
ratio = #[[1]]/Total[#] & /@ xy;
Mean[ratio]
(* 0.322567 *)
```

So they match pretty well.

**Case 2:  $\rho=0$**

Here I could find only the symbolic result for the density of $R|X>0, Y>0$.

```
distxy = BinormalDistribution[{\[Mu]x, \[Mu]y}, {\[Sigma]x, \[Sigma]y}, 0];
distPositive = TruncatedDistribution[{{0, \[Infinity]}, {0, \[Infinity]}}, distxy];
dR = TransformedDistribution[x/(x + y), {x, y} \[Distributed] distPositive, 
   Assumptions -> {\[Sigma]x > 0, \[Sigma]y > 0, \[Mu]x \[Element] Reals, \[Mu]y \[Element] Reals}];
pdf0 = PDF[dR, z]
```

[image: conditional pdf for ratio]

Given that the error functions (`Erf[]` and `Erfc[] = 1- Erf[]` which are functions of the cumulative normal distribution function) are part of the density, it is unlikely that a general symbolic result for the mean exists.  But we can use numerical integration to find the mean for an set of parameters.

```
parms = {\[Mu]x -> 1, \[Mu]y -> 3, \[Sigma]x -> 2, \[Sigma]y -> 7};
NIntegrate[z pdf0 /. parms, {z, 0, 1}]
(* 0.286721 *)

(* Mean from random sampling *)
n = 1000000;
distxy = BinormalDistribution[{\[Mu]x, \[Mu]y}, {\[Sigma]x, \[Sigma]y}, 0] /. parms;
distPositive = TruncatedDistribution[{{0, \[Infinity]}, {0, \[Infinity]}}, distxy];
SeedRandom[12345];
xy = RandomVariate[distPositive /. parms, n];
ratio = #[[1]]/Total[#] & /@ xy;
Mean[ratio]
(* 0.286566 *)
```

These results also match.

**General case**

It would seem that for other combinations of parameters not contained in the first 2 cases, one would need random sampling to approximate the conditional mean.  (I'd like to be wrong about that.)