# Why do I get worse regression metrics when I add more instances to the problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso

I find this counter-intuitive. First I chose randomly 7000 instances and my model explains 55% of the variance. Then I train with the whole dataset (43000) and I get negative $R^2$.

How is this even possible?

This happens with Lasso, elasticnet, ridge regression and SVR with different kernels.

Just for the record, this is how my Y is distributed:
[image]

Comment: Negative $R^2$? Please show such results.

Comment: How many regressors do you have? Did you try multiple samples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question can be answered without referring to regression, based on simpler example of calculating sample mean. In my example I would use two random variables: $X$ that follows [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and $Y$ that follows [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). I am *not* suggesting here that your $Y$ is Cauchy distributed (it *looks* similar), but I am using it just as an example. You can recall that Cauchy distribution is a strange kind of distribution that does not follow [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), has very heavy tails, has no mean and no variance. The plots below show how does mean change with subsequent draws from the distributions (left side) and densities of the distributions after the total $n$ values are drawn, on the top plots you see normal distribution and on the bottom Cauchy. As you can see, when we draw more and more samples from normal distribution, then sample mean converges to population mean. On another hand, Cauchy behaves differently.

[image]

You can find [nice description here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36027/why-does-the-cauchy-distribution-have-no-mean) on why Cauchy has no mean, but basically what happens here is that $Y$ has long tails so with drawing additional values you often draw extreme values and such values influence the mean. If you look again at the plots, you'll see that by pure coincidence we were drawing only values from the extreme positive side of the distribution (it is symmetric), so if we drawn more values and after drawing some number of cases, if we observed value $-15000$ it would obviously impact mean no matter that we already sampled $10000$ cases.

```r
> mean(y)
[1] 2.464524
> mean(c(y,-15000))
[1] 0.9644279
```

With such heavy-tailed variable no matter what regression approach you'll use, you would be focused on the central value of the distribution (mean, median etc.) and you won't be able to make precise estimates for the extreme cases. You can use other approach, e.g. [L1 or quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression), that would provide more robust estimates of central value, but you should ask yourself it is something that you really want to do.

Comment: Are you talking about the marginal or conditional distribution of Y? And do you know of any articles that describe this phenomenon?

Comment: @ssdecontrol the question is pretty vague and refers only to marginal distribution, that is why I focus on estimating mean, since no information is provided about conditional distribution. I mention outliers influencing regression as a general phenomenon. I also would be interested in papers on such cases.

Comment: +1 Congratulations on reaching 10K, Tim.  Your steady contributions over time have been an asset to this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, I am running tests with a dataset of 1335 samples with randomly chosen train and test sets each time. I get really different r2 scores (0.336, 0.896, 0.183, -1.92). This is my Y:
count     13335.000000
mean         38.889989
std        2106.163136
min     -193676.000000
25%         -11.000000
50%          21.000000
75%          62.000000
max       20505.000000