# Metropolis-Hastings Convergence in R

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I'm trying to implement the algorithm Metropolis Hastings for the next FDP.

\begin{equation}
f_{X}(x)=(5+\exp(5/2))*\sqrt{2\pi}\left[\exp\left\{-\frac{(x-2)^{2}-2x}{2}\right\}+5\exp\left\{-\frac{x+2}{2}\right\}\right]
\end{equation}

My problem is that I want to analyze the convergence of average, using the strong law of large numbers. However, by construction, I'm getting a unit root process. Am I making a programming error or this is okay?

This is my code.

```
    rm(list=ls())
    f<-function(x){
      c<-(5+exp(5/2))*sqrt(2*pi) #normalization constant
      (1/c)*(exp(-((x-2)^2-2*x)/2)+5*exp(-((x+2)^2)/2)) #fdp
    }
    integrate(f,-Inf,Inf)
    curve(f(x),-10,10) 

    set.seed(123456)
    nsim<-10^4
    x<-numeric(nsim)
    sigma<-sqrt(1)
    u <- runif(nsim)
    media<-numeric(nsim)
    x[1] <- rnorm(1,runif(1),sigma)
    k<-0
    for (i in 2:nsim) {
      xt <- x[i-1] 
      y <- rnorm(1,xt,sigma) # candidata 
      num <- f(y) * dnorm(xt,y,sigma)
      den <- f(xt) * dnorm(y,xt,sigma)
      if (u[i] <= min(num/den,1)) 
        x[i] <- y else {
          x[i] <- xt
          k <- k+1 # incrementa k porque y fue rechazado
        }
  media[i] <- cumsum(x)/seq_along(x) 
    }

    par(bg = 'gray92')
    plot(media[1000:nsim],type="l", lwd=2, 
         col=8, ylab=expression(bar(x)), xlab="Iteraciones",
         family="serif", main="Media muestral") #convergence of the mean 
    plot(x[6000:6500], type="l")
    hist(x, prob=TRUE, breaks=100, col=2, main="Distribución bimodal", family="serif")
    curve(f(x),-6,6,add=TRUE, lwd=2, col=1)
```

Comment: When i plot this: plot(media[1000:nsim],type="l", lwd=2, 
         col=8, ylab=expression(bar(x)), xlab="Iteraciones",
         family="serif", main="Media muestral"). The mean of the simulated values should convergence, but it does not.

Comment: Doesn't it..? I ran your code and at first glance it seems to converge slowly. Have you tried more than 1e4 iterations (this really isn't that much...)? I don't see what exactly is the problem in here... Can you clarify?

Comment: @Tim Yes, I tried it with 90000 iterations and effectively converge. In previous experiments I had used very low or very high values for the variance. I think the problem was that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not really think that there is *any* problem with convergence in here. You are using pretty small number of iterations in here. There are problems where small number of iterations is ok, but for multiple others *large* number of them is needed. Often it is hard to say how large is large enough.

Considering your data, both fit to the density function

[image]

and traceplots of four runs with different seeds

[image]

look pretty good as far as you increase number of iterations to $10^5$.

As a side-note: notice that there are cases, like [Cauchy distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188126/why-do-i-get-worse-regression-metrics-when-i-add-more-instances-to-the-problem/188132#188132), that do not have mean and do not converge.

I have also a programming comment: the `media[i]<-mean(x[1:i]) #mean` line is useless in your code and slows it down very much, instead you can compute the cumulative means after running it using simply `cumsum(x)/seq_along(x)`, it makes it *much* faster.

Comment: in the last plot you used different seeds to study convergence or different variances?

Comment: @Héctor I just used different seeds