# When does the sum of two $t$-distributed random variables follow a $t$ distribution?

Tags: t-distribution, convolution

In the scope of a project, I need to find the sum of two **independent** $t$-distributions.

I know that in the general case, the sum of two $t$-distributed random variables is not $t$-distributed. However, I would like to know what might be the special cases where the sum of two $t$-distributions is a $t$ distribution.

It would also be nice if someone can give me an example of two such $t$-distributions.

Comment: It is well known, and pointed out in several threads here, that the sum of two *iid* Cauchy (Student $t(1)$) variables again has a Cauchy distribution.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36037/919 for a nice explanation.  I believe that is the only case of this type, as one can show by examining products of Bessel $K$ functions (which are the characteristic functions in the Student t family). Examining the behavior of these functions at infinity might be a simple way to demonstrate this result.

Comment: *In the scope of a project, I need to find the sum of two independent t-distributions.* You could try and tell more about this in a new question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Characteristic functions are handy for studying sums of independent variables,** because the c.f. of the sum is the product of the c.f.s of the addends and c.f.s determine the distribution.

The c.f. of a Student t variable with parameter ("degrees of freedom") $\nu \ge 1$ is, up to a constant of proportionality $C(\nu)$ we don't need to consider, given by

$$\phi_\nu(t) = C(\nu) K_{\nu/2}(|t|\sqrt{\nu})\,|t|^{\nu/2}\tag{*}$$

where $K$ is the [Bessel Function of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).  I promise we won't need to learn much about this function in the following analysis.

Interpreting the question a little more broadly to accommodate a possible change of scale in the result, it asks for all solutions $\nu,\kappa,\mu,\sigma$ to the equation

$$\phi_\nu\,\phi_\kappa= \phi_\mu\circ \lambda_\sigma$$

where all the subscripts are Student t parameters (necessarily positive) and the new scale $\sigma$ is positive; $\lambda_\sigma (t) = \sigma t$ is the change of scale.  According to $(*),$ this equation is equivalent to

$$K_{\nu/2}(|t|\sqrt{\nu})\, K_{\kappa/2}(|t|\sqrt{\kappa}) |t|^{(\nu + \kappa)/2}\ \propto\ K_{\mu/2}(|t|\sigma \sqrt{\mu}) |t|^{\mu/2}.\tag{**}$$

As $|t|$ grows large, $K_\alpha(|t|)$ is [asymptotically proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms) to

$$K_\alpha(|t|) \ \sim\ C(\alpha)e^{-|t|}|t|^{-1/2}\left(1 +  \frac{4\alpha^2-1}{8|t|} + O\left(|t|^{-2}\right)\right).$$

Comparing the leading terms of $(**)$ shows us that

$$e^{-(\sqrt\nu + \sqrt\kappa)|t|}|t|^{(\nu + \kappa)/2-1}\ \propto\ e^{-\sigma\sqrt\mu|t|}|t|^{(\mu-1)/2},$$

equivalent to $\nu+\kappa-1=\mu$ and $\sqrt{\nu}+\sqrt{\kappa} = \sigma\sqrt{\mu}.$  Consequently, *one or both of the original random variables must have a Student $t(1)$ distribution.*  Moreover, taking $\kappa=1$ in that case, whence $\mu=\nu,$ we find $\sigma\sqrt{\nu} = \sqrt{\nu}+1,$ entailing

$$\sigma = 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}}.$$

Comparing the $|t|^{-1}$ terms in the asymptotic expansion shows

$$\frac{4\nu^2-1}{8|t|} =\frac{4\nu^2-1}{8\sigma|t|} + O\left(|t|^{-2}\right)$$

which is possible only when $1 = \sigma = 1 + 1/\sqrt{\nu}$ or $4\nu^2-1=0:$ the only solution is $\nu=1.$

> The sum of two independent Student t variables has a Student t distribution (up to scale) only when both variables have one degree of freedom; and in that case, the resulting distribution has one degree of freedom and a scale factor of $2.$

**As a check,** here is a QQ plot of $|X+Y|$ for a million independent realizations of a Student $t(2)$ variable $Y$ and Student $t(1)$ variable $X$ (shown on a log-log scale due to the heavy tail).

[image: Figure]

(To avoid plotting all million values, only the 0.5%, 1%, ..., 99.5% quantiles of the data are shown.)

The agreement with a $\sigma$ - scaled Student $t(2)$ distribution is good in the middle, but grows increasingly worse out in the tail: adding the heavy-tailed $X$ to $Y$ has given the sum a heavier tail, even after scaling.  It is this deviation at the upper right that the analysis of the $O(|t|^{-1})$ term in the c.f. revealed.

Comment: So if do the sum of two distribution where each one of them has a degree of freedom of 1. I Will get a t distribution with a degree of freedom 2?

Comment: No: this answer shows you obtain a scaled t distribution with $1+1-1=1$ d.f.  I should have made that more explicit in my summary, so I will edit it.

Comment: Thank you it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much less formal approach that (mainly) relies on the fact that moments of order $\nu$ or larger do not exist for Student's t-distributions with $\nu$ degrees of freedom.

If $X_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$ have independent Student's t-distributions with $\nu$ degrees of freedom where the moments of order $\nu$ or higher don't exist, then for the sum ($X_\nu +Y_\nu$) will have the same moments that exist and the same moments that don't exist.  That implies that if the sum were to have a Student's t-distribution, then that distribution would also need to have exactly $\nu$ degrees of freedom.

But for $\nu >2$ the variance is $\nu/(\nu-2)$ for a Student's t-distribution and the sum would have variance $2\nu/(\nu-2)$.  But those two variances can't be the same for $\nu>2$.  So for $\nu>2$, there is no sum of two independent Student's t-distributions degrees of freedom $\nu$ that results in a Student's t-distribution.

That leaves only $\nu=1$ and $\nu=2$ to check.

Comment: Provided we consider non-integral moments, too, this is a nice approach (+1), but it's incomplete: it leaves *all* real values $\nu$ in the interval $(0,2)$ to check.  This is not just a theoretical quibble: Student t distributions with non-integral degrees of freedom are used in several common tests and are often used to approximate other distributions.