# Fundamentals of applied statistics

Tags: expected-value

I'm a begginer in statistics.
I came across a problem, please help me out.
Is expectation always mean arithmetic mean of a variable?

Answer (score -2):

As far as my knowledge go - Yes.

$$E(X) = \sum_{i=0}^n X _i$$

Comment: Does someone else have a better answer.  This is my first answer here on Cross Validated.

Comment: Thank you for your first answer. Can you explain your answer in more detail please? Until now we only have a formula so beginners might have problems understanding what exactly the answer is.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that does not define its terms and it is difficult to supply any interpretation in which the equation describes either an expectation or an arithmetic mean.

Comment: This answer is much more complete:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23781/how-does-the-expected-value-relate-to-mean-median-etc-in-a-non-normal-distrib